# Jquery Replace content in runtime issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I am trying to accomplish is, using jQuery, dynamically replace the content (generated from another javascript) of div tag with id="Test".

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#Test").html('<b>test content</b>');
});
</script>
</head>
<body id="testAgain">
begin
<div class="scrollable">   
    <div class="items" id="Test">
    </div>
</div>
end
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see,

```
$("#Test").html('<b>test content</b>');
```

replaces the html code of div tag with id="Test" with html code

```
<b>test content</b>
```

this works perfectly fine. I am getting rendered html as

```
begin 
test content
end
```

---

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function TestScript(){
document.write('<b>test content</b>');
    };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#Test").html(TestScript());
});
</script>

</head>
<body id="testAgain">
begin
<div class="scrollable">   
    <div class="items" id="Test">
    </div>
</div>

end
</body>
</html>
```

Here,

```
$("#Test").html(TestScript());
```

replaces the html code of div tag with id="Test" with generated html from javascript

```
TestScript()
```

I am getting rendered html as

```
test content
```

It replaces the entire content of the html file. How to resolve this problem?

Kindly help.

Thanks,
John

Comment: Simple, don't use document.write.

Comment: okay thanks. I am new to javascript. my original script is different. I just posted a sample here. so that anyone can test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function TestScript(){
    return '<b>test content</b>';
};
</script>
```

Comment: document.write('blah blah blah');  Does exactly that... writes over the document.